# In need for free flash "image player"

Tags: flash

do you know about some free flash web application which can load images directly from folder and animate them (as a video player)?
I mean, I have a folder with set of images and I want to animate them (switch one by one) in e.g. alphabetic order. Set of images will be randomly cumulate in time therefore I want to automatize this process and that's also why I can't use common video player which works with loading of video file.

Thanks a lot for replies.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Piecemaker](http://www.modularweb.net/content/en/piecemaker/?)?
It's cool, and opensource so its customisable
It loads the pictures from an xml file. More info at the link

Comment: Thanks for reply Pranav. I forgot to mentioned that I'm looking for app which have control buttons (play/pause, stop, window maximalization) and timeline as video player commonly have.

Comment: Found just play, stop, info, link.

Comment: As I said, its customisable, so you can change it to suit your requirements. You already have play, pause and stop (stop = pause). You are going to have to add some code for fullscreen window.